# How to change the docker volume address on host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I create a docker volume in dynamically in my docker-compose file. So it always creates the volume on the host machine at `var/lib/docker/volumes/volume_name/_data`. I need to know 1) how can I change this address in my docker-compose file? 2) how can I read volume name from the `.env` file, say

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  service1:
    image: ...
    container_name: $CONTAINER_NAME
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
        - "$HOSTPORT:5000"
    environment:
        - JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
    volumes:
        - $VOL_NAME:/tmp

volumes:
  $VOL_NAME:
    external: true
```

The reason I'm asking the second question is that apparently name of the volume cannot be parameterized.

Comment: Well, did you read how to use .env files in the Docker documentation?

Answer (score 0):

To read the volume name from the `.env` file, you will need to specify `env_file` in your service.

See example below:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  nginx:
    env_file: .env
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - $VAR:/var/www/develop
```

Testing steps:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:voltest myuser$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   5 myuser  staff   160 12 Sep 15:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  38 myuser  staff  1216 12 Sep 15:03 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff    17 12 Sep 15:04 .env
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff   120 12 Sep 15:04 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser  staff    96 12 Sep 15:04 testfolder

Users-MacBook-Pro:voltest myuser$ ls -la testfolder/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser  staff   96 12 Sep 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 myuser  staff  160 12 Sep 15:06 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff    0 12 Sep 15:04 testfile

Users-MacBook-Pro:voltest myuser$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'
services:
  nginx:
    env_file: .env
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - $VAR:/var/www/develop

Users-MacBook-Pro:voltest myuser$ cat .env
VAR=./testfolder

Users-MacBook-Pro:voltest myuser$ docker-compose exec nginx ls -la /var/www/develop/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            96 Sep 12 19:04 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Sep 12 19:04 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Sep 12 19:04 testfile
```

**Edit: After some back and forth in the comments.**

The configuration you posted won't work with named volumes as the `.env` file will only substitute variables under `services`.

Instead, i'd recommend file system volume mounts. The example below will use relative paths but you could also use absolute.

Files/folders:

```
testfolder1/
   testfile1.txt
testfolder2/
   testfile2.txt
.env
docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  nginx:
    env_file: .env
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - $VAR:/var/www/develop
```

.env

```
VAR=./testfolder2
```

This will mount `./testfolder2` with `testfile2.txt`.

Comment: I have the same the structure and the value of $VOL_NAME is like 'ABCD' but it gives me the following error message: ERROR: The Compose file '././docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
volumes value Additional properties are not allowed ('$VOL_NAME ' was unexpected)

Comment: Can you show me your entire config (edit your post)? Are you using an older docker-compose version? Where are you launching docker-compose from? The `././docker-compose.yaml` reference seems odd.

Comment: I just updated my original post with the docker-compose file and I'm using v 1.18.0

Comment: Oh okay, so not quite the same. The `env_file` is set at the service level so it looks like the volumes definition isn't receiving the value from the `.env` file.

Comment: could you explain more, I didn't quite get that. What should I change?

Comment: also how come you don't have a volumes section at the end? if I remove my volume section is gives me an error

Comment: So based on your current config with an external/named volume, I don't have a solution for you but the problem is that the bottom volume section does not see the environment var from the `.env` file.

Comment: The question is, why are you using a named volume? While I am generally against it, there are valid use cases for it. The reason why I don't have the volumes section at the bottom is because i'm using a file system volume mount which is `./testfolder` relative to the docker-compose file. Maybe you should switch to something like that. That way you could have ./folder1, ./folder2, ./folder3, etc. And then within your .env file, you can specify which one to use.

Comment: could you edit your original post with what I need to change? I mean your new solution (./testfolder)?

Comment: I made the edits. Hopefully I was clear enough in the example. Good luck.